# With FastAPI, How to add charset to content-type (media-type) on request header on OpenAPI (Swagger) doc?

Tags: python-3.x, swagger, openapi, fastapi

With FastAPI, How to  add charset to content-type (media-type) on request header on OpenAPI (Swagger) doc?

```
@app.post("/")
def post_hello(username: str = Form(...)):
   return {"Hello": username}
```

OpenAPI (http:///docs) shows "*application/x-www-form-urlencoded*".

[image: openapi doc]

I tried to change like:

```
def post_hello(username: str = Form(..., media_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=cp932")):
   return {"Hello": "World!", "userName": username}
```

but not be add *charset=cp932*

I want to set "*application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=cp932*" to Content-Type on Request.
And I want to get *username* decoded by the charset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With FastAPI, how do I add `charset` to the Content-Type request header in the automatically generated OpenAPI (Swagger) docs?

```python
@app.post("/")
def post_hello(username: str = Form(...)):
   return {"Hello": username}
```

With the above route, the OpenAPI docs generated at `http://<root_path>/docs` shows `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

[image: openapi docs screenshot with the note unter the Content-Type dropdown 'I want to add charset like "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932"]

I tried this:

```python
@app.post("/")
def post_hello(username: str = Form(..., media_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=cp932")):
   return {"Hello": "World!", "userName": username}
```

But the docs still show only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I want to set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=cp932` as the value
of `Content-Type` in responses from this endpoint/path function. And I want the
form data recieved to be decoded using that encoding scheme.

## Short answer

It doesn't appear to be a good idea in the general case; I don't think there's
an easy<del>, built-in</del> way to do it; and it may not be necessary.

### Not a good idea (a.k.a. not standards-compliant)

[This GitHub issue discusses why appending `;charset=UTF-8` to
`application/json` isn't a good idea,](https://github.com/request/request/issues/383) and the same points
brought up there apply in this case.

[The HTTP/1.1 specification says that the `Content-Type` header lists the Media Type.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1)

*note: [HTTP/2 shares these components with HTTP/1.1](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8)*

[The IANA manages the registry of all the commonly used Media Types (MIME).](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

[The entry for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` says:](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

```
Media type name: application
Media subtype name: x-www-form-urlencoded

Required parameters: No parameters

Optional parameters:
No parameters

Encoding considerations: 7bit
```

Compare this to [the entry for `text/html`:](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html)

```
MIME media type name : Text

MIME subtype name : Standards Tree - html

Required parameters : No required parameters

Optional parameters :
charset
The charset parameter may be provided to definitively specify the document's character encoding, overriding any character encoding declarations in the document. The parameter's value must be one of the labels of the character encoding used to serialize the file.

Encoding considerations : 8bit
```

The entry for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not allow for `charset` to be added. So how should it be decoded from bytes? [The URL spec states:](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing)

> 5. Let *nameString* and *valueString* be the result of running [UTF-8 decode
>    without BOM](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8-decode-without-bom) on the [percent-decoding](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-decode) of *name* and
>    *value*, respectively.

It sounds like, whatever the encoding is, UTF-8 should always be used in
decoding.

[The current HTML/URL specification also has this note about
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

> The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format is in many ways an aberrant
> monstrosity, the result of many years of implementation accidents and
> compromises leading to a set of requirements necessary for interoperability,
> but in no way representing good design practices. In particular, readers are
> cautioned to pay close attention to the twisted details involving repeated
> (and in some cases nested) conversions between character encodings and byte
> sequences. Unfortunately the format is in widespread use due to the
> prevalence of HTML forms.

So it sounds like it wouldn't be a good idea to do something differently.

### <del>No built-in way</del>

---

Note: the built-in way to do what these solutions do is to use [a custom `Request` class.](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/)

---

When building the `/openapi.json` object, the current version of FastAPI
[checks to see if a dependency is an instance of `Form`, and then uses an empty
`Form` instance to build the schema, even if the actual dependency is a
subclass of `Form`.](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.72.0/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L749-L767)

[The default value of the `media_type` parameter of `Form.__init__` is
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.72.0/fastapi/params.py#L274) so every
endpoint/path function with a `Form()` dependency will show the same Media Type
in the docs, even though the class `__init__(` has a `media_type` parameter.

There are a few ways of changing what's listed in `/openapi.json`, which is
what's used to generate the documentation, and [the FastAPI docs list one
official way.](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#generate-the-openapi-schema)

For the example in the question, this would work:

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/")
def post_hello(username: str = Form(...)):
    return {"Hello": username}


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    app.openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title=app.title,
        version=app.version,
        openapi_version=app.openapi_version,
        description=app.description,
        terms_of_service=app.terms_of_service,
        contact=app.contact,
        license_info=app.license_info,
        routes=app.routes,
        tags=app.openapi_tags,
        servers=app.servers,
    )

    requestBody = app.openapi_schema["paths"]["/"]["post"]["requestBody"]
    content = requestBody["content"]
    new_content = {
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932": content[
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
    }
    requestBody["content"] = new_content

    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi
```

It's worth noting that, with this change, the docs user interface changes how it presents the experimentation section:

[image: a screenshot showing a text box input prefilled with a JSON object of {"username": "string"}]

Compared to how just `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with no `charset`
specified is shown:

[image: a screenshot showing a form input with a single field named "username"]

The above changes would only change th Media Type listed in the docs. Any form
data sent to an endpoint/path function would still be:

1. [parsed by `python-multipart`](https://github.com/andrew-d/python-multipart/blob/0.0.5/multipart/multipart.py#L798-L939) (roughly following [the
   same steps described in the specification](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-parsing))
2. [decoded by `starlette` with `Latin-1`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/formparsers.py#L106-L107)

So even if `starlette` was changed to use a different encoding scheme for
decoding form data, [`python-multipart` still follows the steps outlined in the
specification to use hardcoded byte values for `&` and `;`, for
example.](https://github.com/andrew-d/python-multipart/blob/0.0.5/multipart/multipart.py#L67-L68)

Fortunately, [most***** of the first 128 characters/codepoints are mapped to the same byte sequences between cp932 and UTF-8,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)#Single-byte_character_differences) so `&`,
`;`, and `=` all come out the same.

******except for `0x5C`, which is sometimes `¥`*

One way to change `starlette` to use cp932 encoding would be using a [middleware:](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/)

```python
import typing
from unittest.mock import patch
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

import multipart
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request, Response
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from multipart.multipart import parse_options_header
from starlette.datastructures import FormData, UploadFile
from starlette.formparsers import FormMessage, FormParser

app = FastAPI()

form_path = "/"


@app.post(form_path)
async def post_hello(username: str = Form(...)):
    return {"Hello": username}


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    app.openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title=app.title,
        version=app.version,
        openapi_version=app.openapi_version,
        description=app.description,
        terms_of_service=app.terms_of_service,
        contact=app.contact,
        license_info=app.license_info,
        routes=app.routes,
        tags=app.openapi_tags,
        servers=app.servers,
    )

    requestBody = app.openapi_schema["paths"]["/"]["post"]["requestBody"]
    content = requestBody["content"]
    new_content = {
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932": content[
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
    }
    requestBody["content"] = new_content

    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi


class CP932FormParser(FormParser):
    async def parse(self) -> FormData:
        """
        copied from:
        https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/formparsers.py#L72-L110
        """
        # Callbacks dictionary.
        callbacks = {
            "on_field_start": self.on_field_start,
            "on_field_name": self.on_field_name,
            "on_field_data": self.on_field_data,
            "on_field_end": self.on_field_end,
            "on_end": self.on_end,
        }

        # Create the parser.
        parser = multipart.QuerystringParser(callbacks)
        field_name = b""
        field_value = b""

        items: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, typing.Union[str, UploadFile]]] = []

        # Feed the parser with data from the request.
        async for chunk in self.stream:
            if chunk:
                parser.write(chunk)
            else:
                parser.finalize()
            messages = list(self.messages)
            self.messages.clear()
            for message_type, message_bytes in messages:
                if message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_START:
                    field_name = b""
                    field_value = b""
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_NAME:
                    field_name += message_bytes
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_DATA:
                    field_value += message_bytes
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_END:
                    name = unquote_plus(field_name.decode("cp932"))  # changed line
                    value = unquote_plus(field_value.decode("cp932"))  # changed line
                    items.append((name, value))

        return FormData(items)


class CustomRequest(Request):
    async def form(self) -> FormData:
        """
        copied from
        https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/requests.py#L238-L253
        """
        if not hasattr(self, "_form"):
            assert (
                parse_options_header is not None
            ), "The `python-multipart` library must be installed to use form parsing."
            content_type_header = self.headers.get("Content-Type")
            content_type, options = parse_options_header(content_type_header)
            if content_type == b"multipart/form-data":
                multipart_parser = MultiPartParser(self.headers, self.stream())
                self._form = await multipart_parser.parse()
            elif content_type == b"application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
                form_parser = CP932FormParser(
                    self.headers, self.stream()
                )  # use the custom parser above
                self._form = await form_parser.parse()
            else:
                self._form = FormData()
        return self._form


@app.middleware("http")
async def custom_form_parser(request: Request, call_next) -> Response:
    if request.scope["path"] == form_path:
        # starlette creates a new Request object for each middleware/app
        # invocation:
        # https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/routing.py#L59
        # this temporarily patches the Request object starlette
        # uses with our modified version
        with patch("starlette.routing.Request", new=CustomRequest):
            return await call_next(request)
```

Then, the data has to be encoded manually:

```pycon
>>> import sys
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> name = quote_plus("username").encode("cp932")
>>> value = quote_plus("cp932文字コード").encode("cp932")
>>> with open("temp.txt", "wb") as file:
...     file.write(name + b"=" + value)
...
59
```

And sent as binary data:

```shellsession
$ curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932' \
  --data-binary "@temp.txt" \
  --silent \
| jq -C .

{
  "Hello": "cp932文字コード"
}
```

### Might not be necessary

In the manual encoding step, the output will look like:

```
username=cp932%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89
```

Part of the [percent-encoding](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#string-percent-encode-after-encoding) step replaces any bytes representing
characters higher than `0x7E` (`~` in ASCII) with bytes in a reduced ASCII
range. Since [cp932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)#Single-byte_character_differences) and UTF-8 both map these bytes to the same codepoints
(except for `0x5C` which may be `\` or `¥`), the byte sequence will decode to
the same string:

```shellsession
$ curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932' \
  --data-urlencode "username=cp932文字コード" \
  --silent \
| jq -C .

{
  "Hello": "cp932文字コード"
}
```

This is only true for [percent-encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#string-percent-encode-after-encoding) data.

Any data sent without [percent-encoding](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#string-percent-encode-after-encoding) will be processed and interpreted
differently from how the sender intended it to be interpreted. For example, in
the OpenAPI (Swagger) docs, the "Try it out" experimentation section gives an
example with [`curl -d` (same as `--data`), which doesn't urlencode the data](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d):

```shellsession
$ curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data "username=cp932文字コード" \
  --silent \
| jq -C .
{
  "Hello": "cp932æ–‡å­—ã‚³ãƒ¼ãƒ‰"
}
```

It might still be a good idea to only use cp932 to process requests from senders that are configured in a way similar to the server.

One way to do this would be to modify the middleware function to only process
data like this if the sender specifies that the data has been encoded with
cp932:

```python
import typing
from unittest.mock import patch
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

import multipart
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request, Response
from fastapi.openapi.utils import get_openapi
from multipart.multipart import parse_options_header
from starlette.datastructures import FormData, UploadFile
from starlette.formparsers import FormMessage, FormParser

app = FastAPI()

form_path = "/"


@app.post(form_path)
async def post_hello(username: str = Form(...)):
    return {"Hello": username}


def custom_openapi():
    if app.openapi_schema:
        return app.openapi_schema

    app.openapi_schema = get_openapi(
        title=app.title,
        version=app.version,
        openapi_version=app.openapi_version,
        description=app.description,
        terms_of_service=app.terms_of_service,
        contact=app.contact,
        license_info=app.license_info,
        routes=app.routes,
        tags=app.openapi_tags,
        servers=app.servers,
    )

    requestBody = app.openapi_schema["paths"]["/"]["post"]["requestBody"]
    content = requestBody["content"]
    new_content = {
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=cp932": content[
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ]
    }
    requestBody["content"] = new_content

    return app.openapi_schema


app.openapi = custom_openapi


class CP932FormParser(FormParser):
    async def parse(self) -> FormData:
        """
        copied from:
        https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/formparsers.py#L72-L110
        """
        # Callbacks dictionary.
        callbacks = {
            "on_field_start": self.on_field_start,
            "on_field_name": self.on_field_name,
            "on_field_data": self.on_field_data,
            "on_field_end": self.on_field_end,
            "on_end": self.on_end,
        }

        # Create the parser.
        parser = multipart.QuerystringParser(callbacks)
        field_name = b""
        field_value = b""

        items: typing.List[typing.Tuple[str, typing.Union[str, UploadFile]]] = []

        # Feed the parser with data from the request.
        async for chunk in self.stream:
            if chunk:
                parser.write(chunk)
            else:
                parser.finalize()
            messages = list(self.messages)
            self.messages.clear()
            for message_type, message_bytes in messages:
                if message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_START:
                    field_name = b""
                    field_value = b""
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_NAME:
                    field_name += message_bytes
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_DATA:
                    field_value += message_bytes
                elif message_type == FormMessage.FIELD_END:
                    name = unquote_plus(field_name.decode("cp932"))  # changed line
                    value = unquote_plus(field_value.decode("cp932"))  # changed line
                    items.append((name, value))

        return FormData(items)


class CustomRequest(Request):
    async def form(self) -> FormData:
        """
        copied from
        https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/requests.py#L238-L253
        """
        if not hasattr(self, "_form"):
            assert (
                parse_options_header is not None
            ), "The `python-multipart` library must be installed to use form parsing."
            content_type_header = self.headers.get("Content-Type")
            content_type, options = parse_options_header(content_type_header)
            if content_type == b"multipart/form-data":
                multipart_parser = MultiPartParser(self.headers, self.stream())
                self._form = await multipart_parser.parse()
            elif content_type == b"application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
                form_parser = CP932FormParser(
                    self.headers, self.stream()
                )  # use the custom parser above
                self._form = await form_parser.parse()
            else:
                self._form = FormData()
        return self._form


@app.middleware("http")
async def custom_form_parser(request: Request, call_next) -> Response:
    if request.scope["path"] != form_path:
        return await call_next(request)

    content_type_header = request.headers.get("content-type", None)
    if not content_type_header:
        return await call_next(request)

    media_type, options = parse_options_header(content_type_header)
    if b"charset" not in options or options[b"charset"] != b"cp932":
        return await call_next(request)

    # starlette creates a new Request object for each middleware/app
    # invocation:
    # https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/0.17.1/starlette/routing.py#L59
    # this temporarily patches the Request object starlette
    # uses with our modified version
    with patch("starlette.routing.Request", new=CustomRequest):
        return await call_next(request)
```

### Security

Even with this modification, I think the note in the spec about parsing content
with [percent-decode](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-decode) should also be highlighted:

> ⚠ Warning! *Using anything but UTF-8 decode without BOM when* input *contains bytes that
> are not ASCII bytes might be insecure and is not recommended.*

So I would be cautious about implementing any of these solutions at all.