# Decoding non-utf-8 request bodies with fastapi

Tags: windows, character-encoding, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

I have what feels like a simple question: I have a service using fastapi that receives requests in which the request bodies have been encoded using the `ISO-8859-1` encoding and the `content-type` in the request header is set to `text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1`.

I can manually decode the request body without issue:

```py
async def myendpoint(request: Request) -> str:
    body = await request.body()
    content_type = request.headers.get("content-type", "")
    _, options = cgi.parse_header(content_type)
    encoding = options.get("charset", "utf-8")
    decoded_body = body.decode(encoding)
    return decoded_body
```

But I'd really like to have the endpoint take a pydantic model instead of a Request, in which case fastapi also decodes the request body automatically...and as far as I can tell, it always uses `utf-8` regardless of what the `content-type` header says, and I can't find any way to alter this behavior.

Is there something really obvious that I'm missing here? I find it hard to believe that a service framework that automatically decodes the request body would just assume `utf-8` for everything. And if this really is just how it works, do I have better options beyond doing the decoding (and validation through pydantic, and exception handling for that validation...) myself, in the endpoint function?

Comment: Using anything other than UTF-8 in an API is a bad choice to begin with. Not only is this the de-facto standard since the early 2000s, it's actually required for JSON. Why not change the *client* to work the same way all other clients do?

Comment: This means that if you want Pydantic to parse JSON requests, the encoding [*MUST* be UTF-8.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1): `JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70786846/11612918) both goes over why this is a bad idea, and suggests methods for how to implement.

Comment: I see, that clarifies a lot, thank you! I understood that UTF-8 was very commonly used, but I didn't realize it was literally the standard encoding for JSON. I agree that changing the client to conform to the standard makes the most sense, then. Thanks!